# Can I have both web and api guards in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So far I used API only from website (for AJAX reqeusts), so I applied `web` middleware, but I'm going to build mobile app using same methods and routes.
I tried to use `auth:api` middleware on `\api\` routes but it forces me to use token in every request.
Is there any way to distinguish what kind of authentication is used then apply proper middleware?

Comment: Please show us the code you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply different middleware to the same controllers/routes through a different URL.

Assuming Laravel 5.4, then somewhere in your `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
Route::middleware('web')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

Route::prefix('api')
     ->middleware(['auth:api', 'web'])
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

Notice that both route groups have the same route file and the same namespace but the second one has a different set of middlewar and a URL prefix.